# How to show tooltips for react-select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I need to show tooltips for react-select container (not for a separate options) using `react-tooltip` library.

I made my own `SelectContainer` component based on the original one and added there `data-tip` and `data-for` HTML attributes. Tooltip shows up but when I change selected value it disappears and is not displayed any more.

Here is my code:

```js
const getSelectContainer = options => props => {
  return (
    <components.SelectContainer
      {...props}
      innerProps={{
        ...props.innerProps, ...{
          'data-tip': options.tooltipText,
          'data-for': options.tooltipId,
        }
      }}
    />
  )
}

const CustomSelect = (props) => {
  const tooltipId='tooltip_id'
  const tooltipText='tooltip'
  const selectedOption = colourOptions.filter(option => option.value === props.value)
  
  return (
    <div>
      <ReactTooltip effect="solid" html={true} place="bottom" id={tooltipId} />
      <Select
        defaultValue={colourOptions[4]}
        value={selectedOption}
        options={colourOptions}
        classNamePrefix="react-select"
        onChange={item => props.onChange(item.value)}
        className="my-select"
        components={{
          SelectContainer: getSelectContainer({
            tooltipText:tooltipText,
            tooltipId:tooltipId
          })
        }}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

class Page extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      selectValue: 'red'
    }
  }
  render () {
    const onChange = (value)=> {
      this.setState({selectValue: value})
      //alert(value)
    }
    return (
      <CustomSelect
        value={this.state.selectValue}
        onChange={onChange}>
      </CustomSelect>
    )
  }
}
```

See full [example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-4xuss):

If I wrap `Select` with another `<div>` and assign tooltip HTML attributes to it everything works correctly but I don't want to add one more DOM element just for that.

What can I do to show tooltips after changing selection?

Answer (score 2):

Try rebuilding the react-tooltip when the state changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
    ReactTooltip.rebuild();
}, [state]);
```

Comment: Thank you. I have stateless component so I don't use [state]. Here is the [updated code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-iymky).

Comment: Just to note that I wrote that answer using React Hooks.  The `state` in the dependency list of that example comes from a `useReducer`.